# 'Except' function not working as expected after moving to spark 3.0.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I recently moved to spark 3.0.1 from spark 2.4 and after that, I am facing an issue where 'except' function is not working as expected. Here are the outputs of two data frames which I am working with -

```
expected_df.show(false)
+--------+------------------------------------+
|duration|regardingobjectid                   |
+--------+------------------------------------+
|1730.0  |9cd27e8e-061d-435b-89bf-a0ad2c2b11f3|
|1142.5  |509c2aaf-75a7-492d-9a71-35d207617097|
|1082.5  |a75eb211-de50-429f-bc16-1778938701cb|
|1127.5  |9457eb9e-f207-4ba6-a268-eb6b3a4d268d|
|1400.0  |8506bd67-9e00-440b-9b36-ffbbf4472c15|
|7.5     |568b9d9b-a4ac-4dee-80b2-9db989d9f9e4|
+--------+------------------------------------+

actual_df.show(false)
+--------+------------------------------------+
|duration|regardingobjectid                   |
+--------+------------------------------------+
|1082.5  |a75eb211-de50-429f-bc16-1778938701cb|
|1127.5  |9457eb9e-f207-4ba6-a268-eb6b3a4d268d|
|1142.5  |509c2aaf-75a7-492d-9a71-35d207617097|
|1400.0  |8506bd67-9e00-440b-9b36-ffbbf4472c15|
|7.5     |568b9d9b-a4ac-4dee-80b2-9db989d9f9e4|
|1730.0  |9cd27e8e-061d-435b-89bf-a0ad2c2b11f3|
+--------+------------------------------------+
```

As one can see from the above output, the data is the same in the above dataframes. When I use except function to find the diff between these dataframes, this is the output which I get -

```
actual_df.except(expected_df).show(false)
+--------+-----------------+
|duration|regardingobjectid|
+--------+-----------------+
+--------+-----------------+

expected_df.except(actual_df).show(false)
+--------+------------------------------------+
|duration|regardingobjectid                   |
+--------+------------------------------------+
|1082.5  |a75eb211-de50-429f-bc16-1778938701cb|
|1127.5  |9457eb9e-f207-4ba6-a268-eb6b3a4d268d|
|1142.5  |509c2aaf-75a7-492d-9a71-35d207617097|
|1400.0  |8506bd67-9e00-440b-9b36-ffbbf4472c15|
|1730.0  |9cd27e8e-061d-435b-89bf-a0ad2c2b11f3|
+--------+------------------------------------+
```

In the first case, the output of except is rightly empty, but in the second case, it only removes one row and keeps the others.

The same code works perfectly fine with Spark 2.4.

I verified using 'printSchema' that the data types are the same for both the dataframes.

**Also verified that the subtract method works fine when I convert the above dataframes to RDDs.**

Is there a behaviour change with respect to 'except' function, which I might be missing here?

Comment: Not reproducible on Spark 3 for me. What's the data type of duration? float?

Comment: 'duration' is of type Double. Here is the output of printSchema -                                    ` root
 |-- duration: double (nullable = true)
 |-- regardingobjectid: string (nullable = true)`